# how to overcome this case?

Tags: python-3.x, list, size

I have a program that read a CSV file line by line and for each line, I process some values and store them in a list then append them to a list, in the end, I have a list of lists.

Since I test on small files, it's ok. But when it will come to a large file I need to predict the machine memory behavior, to do so I need to know how a 200.000.000(for example) lines processed will need of memory.

I've tried something but then I encountered this problem that I've simplified in below.

```
from sys import getsizeof

# Code 1
print("{} bytes".format(getsizeof([['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source']*4])))

# 72 bytes

###### different from ######

# Code 2
print("{} bytes".format(getsizeof([['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source'],
           ['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source'],
           ['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source'],
           ['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source']])))

# 96 bytes

# when checking the unique identity 

> [id(['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source'])*4]
 [10301192613920]

> [    id(['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source']),
       id(['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source']),
       id(['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source']),
       id(['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source'])   ]
[2575297689160, 2575297689160, 2575297689160, 2575297689160]
```

The size in bytes is different like if there is some kind of indexing in the memory of the object/value when you try in the way of Code 1. How can I overcome this and make my approximative estimation?

Comment: Can you elaborate? If you are reading a CSV line by line the memory depends on the size of that line (number of characters etc) but that shouldn't be a problem. What exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to estimate how much memory will be needed for a list of lists that contains three values, like in the code example.

Comment: If you are iterating over a file, only memory needed will just be the memory needed by that particular iteration. Is that what you want to know? Since it is a sequential operation memory (RAM) for small as well as large (2000000 lines) files will be similar as long as you are iterating. Only that this will take a lot of time.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but my concern is about the final list: for each line I iterate over, I recover three values as a list then append them to another list. At the end i will end up with a list [ [val1,val2,val3]*nbr_lines ]; so I'm looking for the size of  [ [val1,val2,val3]*nbr_line ].

Comment: Alright got your requirement now! What's with `id`? why are you using `id` in your code?

Comment: that code is not my main code, it's just an aside snippet of code where I try to simulate my use case to calculate the size of my list of lists to see how much memory I need to stock it.

Comment: I found the problem, it was a wrong usage of list*number to repeat lists. ```bytes= getsizeof([['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source']]*200000000)
print("{} bytes".format(bytes))  #is not the same as   print("{} bytes".format(getsizeof([['3657f9f6395fc3ef8fe640','table_source','field_source']*200000000]))) ``` now i can estimate that for 200000000 line, i need (6400000064 bytes <=> 6.400000064 gb) for usage in memory.

Comment: Great!! Keep up the good work.